# DbSet Find always return null

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm building url shortener to improve my skills in ASP.NET Core, but came into a problem with using Entity Framework - `.Find()` method always return `null` from my database.

First of all, Im created db record class with custom **Key** field

```cs
public class DbField
    {
        [Key]
        public string hash { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
    }
```

Then applied it in a context

```cs
public class UrlShorterContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<DbField> UrlHashes { get; set; }

        public UrlShorterContext(DbContextOptions<UrlShorterContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
```

Add context to services in `ConfigureServices` with

```cs
string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContext<UrlShorterContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

And then applied it in a controller

```cs
UrlShorterContext db;

public HomeController(UrlShorterContext context)
{
      db = context;
}


public IActionResult Index(string url,[FromServices] IComputeHash computeService)
        {
            string urlHash = computeService.Compute(url);//generates hash from url
            DbField field = db.UrlHashes.Find(urlHash);
            if (field == null)
            { 
                db.UrlHashes.Add(new DbField { hash = urlHash, link = url });
                return View("View1");
            }
            return View("View2");
...
```

In first run db is empty, *action* gets url, hashes it, add's to database and returns "View1".
In second run with same url it must be found in `.Find()` method, `field` must be assigned to its value and "View2" must be returned. But somehow `field` get value of `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the hashed url to the UrlHashes DbSet, you need to call `.SaveChanges()` to make sure the changes are written to the DB.

```
string urlHash = computeService.Compute(url);//generates hash from url
DbField field = db.UrlHashes.Find(urlHash);

if (field == null)
{ 
    db.UrlHashes.Add(new DbField { hash = urlHash, link = url });
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View("View1");
}

return View("View2");
```

You should also look into making this action async and calling `.SaveChangesAsync()`